# NetBeans Ruby plugin install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, proxy

I installed NetBeans 7.3.1 onto my mac and then proceeded to download the necessary Ruby plugin to allow for Ruby in the IDE. However when I go to add the plugin file I get this message:

Unable to connect to the ruby because of Unexpected closed connection to file:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/updates

Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your firewall is not blocking network traffic.

Help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hello, is anyone out there to help on this?

Answer (score 9):

This post might help you. https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/ruby_on_rails_in_netbeans

1. Go to "Tools > Plugins",
2. Select "Downloaded" tab
3. Click on "Add Plugins ..."
4. Navigate to your updates folder
5. Select only the *.nbm files

Comment: You need to add the `.jar` file as well otherwise you get dependancy warnings.

Answer (score 4):

in addition to picking the .nbm files from the unzipped folder, the .jar file must also be added to the plugin selection for the plugin to install. You can use the 'show all files' drop down menu option in the selection dialog box to add the .jar file to the included file list.

Comment: That works fine for me "...jar file must also be added to the plugin selection for the plugin to install" Thanks